# How to make sure an iterator template parameter has the same data type as the template parameter of a template class

Tags: c++, templates, stl, iterator

Sorry for the long title... Please let me know how to make it better...

I have a template class:

```
template <typename T>
class Example {
    ...
    template <typename Iterator>
    void add(const Iterator begin, const Iterator end);
    ...
};
```

How do I ensure the data type pointed by `Iterator` is `T`?

Another related question:

How does this STL vector constructor

```
template <class InputIterator>
vector (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, 
    const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

make sure the `InputIterator` has a compatible data type as the vector?

**Edit:**

Is there a compile time solution?

Comment: Something along the lines of `static_assert(is_same<decltype(*begin), T>::value)`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik May need a `decay` in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
template <typename Iterator>
void add(const Iterator begin, const Iterator end)
{
   static_assert(std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type,
                 T>::value, "Iterator must be the same as T");
}
```

Comment: But this works at runtime. Is there a solution at compile time?

Comment: @Zhi: it is a compile time check.

Comment: @Zhi A `static_assert` is a compile-time assertion.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to make sure  the data type pointed by Iterator is T:

```
template <typename T>
class Example 
{
public:
    void add(const T* begin, const T* end)
    {
    }
};
```

vector constructor doesn't make sure the InputIterator has a compatible data type as the vector.It just allocates memory and assigns the elements.So if the data type pointed by InputIterator can cast to vector type implicitly,it compiles successfully,which doesn't guarantee the right assignment behavior.Otherwise it reports errors.eg:

```
char a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
vector<int> ivec(a, a + 2);
```

this can be successfully complied.

```
string str[3] = {"a", "b", "c"};
vector<int> ivec(str, str + 2);
```

this doesn't.